# How to use regex to look around a complex pattern?

Tags: regex

I have the following html element in Sublime Text:

```
<div class="exg"><div><strong class="syn">investigate</strong><span class="syn">, conduct investigations into, make inquiries into, inquire into, probe, examine, explore, research, study, look into, go into</span></div>
```

I want to use regex to select the content after and including the 5th comma in this element, stopping before
`</span></div>`.
So, in this case I'd want to select:

```
, examine, explore, research, study, look into, go into
```

So far, I was able to write this regex, which works:

```
(<div class="exg"><div><strong class="syn">(\w+)((\s)?(\w+)?)+</strong><span class="syn">((\,((\s)?(\w+)?)+)?){5})
```

This allows me to select the part **before** what I need to select. I tried to use this with a positive lookbehind, but it isn't working and I can't figure out how to fix it. Here is what I tried:

```
(?<=(<div class="exg"><div><strong class="syn">(\w+)((\s)?(\w+)?)+</strong><span class="syn">((\,((\s)?(\w+)?)+)?){3}))((\,?((\s)?(\w+)?)+?)+)
```

Comment: what language do you use? variable width lookbehinds are not available in all regex engines...

Comment: There must be some way to achieve the result with regex though, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a heavy use of parenthesis. Also your expression for catching words between commas could be simpler. Replacing your groups with non capturing ones, you'll get the expected match in your first (and only) group with this regex:

```
(?<=<div class="exg"><div><strong class="syn">)(?:\s?\w)*<\/strong><span class="syn">(?:,(?:\s?\w)*){4}(.*?)(?=<\/span><\/div>)
```

BTW if you want to capture the 5th comma I think your quantifier should be `{4}` (but I might have misunderstood)

Check the [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HspubD/1)

Update:
If you're looking to delete the matched group (i.e. replacing it with an empty string). Just do the opposite: build one group before and one after:

```
(<div class="exg"><div><strong class="syn">(?:\s?\w)*<\/strong><span class="syn">(?:,(?:\s?\w)*){4}).*?(<\/span><\/div>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QkGNPa/1)
Then replace in your editor with `\1\2`(groups one after the other, without the previously matched string inbetween)

Comment: I tried to use find and replace with this in Sublime Text and it just deleted all of the following: `investigate</strong><span class="syn">, conduct investigations into, make inquiries into, inquire into, probe, examine, explore, research, study, look into, go into`

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? remove everything except the first group? you should update your question as well

Comment: I want to remove the following: `, examine, explore, research, study, look into, go into`

Comment: which part of the question is confusing or needs to be updated?

Comment: in your question you only mention that you want to *select* this part of the string. You should mention that you want to delete it. cause what we actually do (check my updated answer!) is capturing the rest to replace it with groups that are *not* what you initially wanted to select

Comment: It works now! Thank you so much for the help! This did solve my issue, but I specifically wrote the question that way because I wanted to see if it was possible just to select it. Who knows, maybe someone will be able to figure it out

Comment: Also (for anybody reading this) if \1\2 doesn't work, try $1$2 instead